# CouchDB updates functions not working

Tags: couchdb, handler, updates

I'm tried it like this

[image: without tokens]

And like this

[image: with tokens]

But no luck — I'm always getting this:

[image: no way]

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your design document is invalid.

- Multiline strings are not valid in JSON (use "\n" or strip all line feeds)
- I think you are missing { and } around your object declaration.

To avoid errors directly use the json view on the admin console, or update your views with scripts instead of doing it by hand.

Your end result should look like this:

[image: example]

Comment: Thanks, it working now. Turned all to single-line and packed up with braces.